# OnClientClick isn't firing for ImageButton

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, imagebutton, onclientclick

I have an ASP.NET ImageButton that OnClientClick() is supposed to fire a js function that reads the values from a two text fields, send it to a server-side WebMethod. With the WebMethod sending it to another entity method which handles the storage. I've tried debugging by setting breakpoints in the WebMethod and storage method on the serverside but neither is getting reached. I then tried setting a breakpoint on client-side using the Mozilla Firebug tool. The js function never gets called and the page just refreshes. I set a breakpoint in another js function and it was traced perfectly. Any help?

```
ASP
<asp:ImageButton input="image" ID="btnSend" ImageUrl="Images/send_button.jpg" 
   runat="server"                                                            
   onclientclick="javascript:handle(); return false">
</asp:ImageButton>


JS
function handle() {
        window.$get("#" + "<%= btnSend.ClientID %>").click(
            function () {
                var txtVC = window.$get("#" + "<%= txtVC.ClientID %>").value();
                var txtMsg = window.$get("#" + "<%= tbMgSend.ClientID %>").value();

                if (txtVC != "" || txtMsg != "") {
                    window.PageMethods.SendMsg(txtVC, txtMsg, txtMessageResult);
                    return window.$get("#" + "<%= lblMessageStatus.ClientID%>").value("SUCCESS"), 
                    alert("SUCCESS");
                }
                else {
                    return alert("Text Message is Empty!");
                }
            });
    }

function txtMsgResult(result) {
        if (result != '') {
            window.$("#" + "<%= lblMessageStatus.ClientID %>").innerHTML = result;
            alert("SUCCESS");
        }
    }
```

I've tried the following:
  * OnclientClick with and without return 
  * $get with and without concat(+)
  * changing the server-side to a method instead of web method and that also didn't fire

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried it without the `return false`?

```
<asp:ImageButton input="image" ID="btnSend" ImageUrl="Images/send_button.jpg" 
   runat="server"                                                            
  onclientclick="handle()">
</asp:ImageButton>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it doesn't work because it autoPostBack.
I'm not sure there is a way to turn it off in an ImageButton. Why not use a HTML control instead ?